# Transaction Validation

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, input-script, witness-data

What will it mean if the tranasaction input contains both signature script and witness, in case of scriptpubkey_type of p2sh or p2pkh, will it be invalid or valid ? As we use witness for SegWit Transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any input spending a non-segwit script type must not have a witness. If it does, the transaction is invalid.

P2SH-P2WSH and P2SH-P2WPKH are the exceptions: if the script type is P2SH *and* the redeemScript is P2WSH or P2WPKH, then a witness is allowed, and is verified according to the P2WSH and P2WPKH verification rules.

Comment: how is it determined when p2wsh is nested with p2sh or p2wpkh is nested with p2sh?

Comment: It is determined during script evaluation. When a P2SH is evaluated and the redeemScript pulled out as part of that, the redeemScript is inspected to see if it is P2WPKH or P2WSH.